# I need to fetch the data from mysql database using the employee id from the table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch the data from the table using the employee id,

there are two tables

1."user_info" which contains    id, name,password,email,ScheduleDate,etc!

2."fetch" which contains id,ScheduleDate,starttime,endtime,hours,employeeid.

if i give the name and the password it takes the id of the particular user from "user_info" and it should send the id as the employee id to the table "fetch" and it should fetch the data from that employee id.

User_info database

[image]

fetch database

[image]

for example if i give the input as name :rajesh password:1995 in user_info,it should take the id of this user and it should send the id as employee id as 15 to the "fetch" table.

when i tried to send the id as employee id it doesn't print anything,and didn't show any error.

```
           <?php
     require "init.php";
     $name = "surya";
     $password = "1995";
        $Sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info` 
        WHERE `name`='".$name."' AND 
        `password`='".$password."';";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $Sql);
$retrive = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $user_id =  $row['id']; 



    $sql = "SELECT id, ScheduleDate, StartTime,Endtime, Hours,Employeeid 
    FROM empdet WHERE Employeeid ='".$user_id."' ";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $id=$row["id"]. 
        $date=$row["ScheduleDate"]; 
        $start=$row["StartTime"]; 
        $end=$row["Endtime"];
        $hour=$row["Hours"];
        $Employeeid=$row["Employeeid"];
        list($year,$month,$day) = split("-",$date);
        $data[] = array("year"=>$year,
                       "month"=>$month,
                       "day"=>$day,
                       "StartTime"=>$start,
                       "Endtime"=>$end,
                       "Hours"=>$hour );

    } 
    $response = $data;
} else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}

}

echo json_encode(array("user_data"=> $response)); 

   ?>
```

i need to fetch all the 3 data from the "fetch" table using the employee id 15.can anyone help to find it out this?

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: Inevitable warning about storing password as clear text in the database. Not part of your question, but something you should be aware of the danger.

Comment: Based from your codes, you are using `surya` which have a `id` of 9, but you want to fetch data that have the `employeeid` of 15. Normally, you will never be able to fetch those data that belong to 15, because you are using an `id` of 9. Or that is just an example?

Comment: its a sample database,it is not used anywhere so no worries!@ cmiller.

Comment: Try using `print_r($rows)` to see if the array actually contains what you expect. Also, you should be using prepared statements to avoid the possibility of SQL injection.

Comment: Sample database or not, you should _always_ follow best practices to get in the habit of writing *good code*.

Comment: @swellar sorry sir,its rajesh not surya,i edited it.

Comment: when i tried to print the user_info entries,it is working,but when i tried to print the entries from fetch table,it is not working,my dout is weather i am using correct query,or i should change any statement or i should use seperate loop for that.

Comment: Hi, just add a loop after your second query execution, it will work for you.

Comment: can you tell me how to put loop? @ patrick

Comment: I have posted answer with sample code, see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding your code is correct till second query. In that query execution, you will get multiple records. So you need to use loop for that.

See below example code:

```
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $date=$rows["ScheduleDate"];
    $start=$rows["StartTime"];
    $end=$rows["Endtime"];
    $hour=$rows["Hours"];
    list($year,$month,$day) = split("-",$date);
    $data[] = array("year"=>$year,
                       "month"=>$month,
                       "day"=>$day,
                       "StartTime"=>$start,
                       "Endtime"=>$end,
                       "Hours"=>$hour );
    }
    $response = $data;
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: its not working sir,nor its shows any error,blank page is displayed

Comment: i have edited the code what you have said,please check weather i have done it correct!

Comment: See my updated answer, I have added while loop code. Check variables properly before you execute!

Comment: thanks for your help,everything is correct but working,so i deleted the database and created again new db,and i run this code,and this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'INNER JOIN' to achieve what you want:

```
$sql = "SELECT fetch.ScheduleDate, fetch.StartTime, fetch.Endtime, fetch.Hours"
." FROM fetch INNER JOIN user_info ON fetch.id = user_info.id"
." WHERE user_info.name = ? AND user_info.password = ? ";

//Prepare statement
$stmt = $mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

//Bind parameter (id)
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, ss, $name, $password);

//Execute statement
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

//Bind results
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $date, $start, $end, $hour);

//Fetch values (puts the values into the variables)
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```